# If gravitational lines of force emerge out of massive bodies, why don't they repel?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, vector-fields

Can the attractive property of gravity be explained using lines of force?
Or is it only possible to explain it through the quantum field theory?
*I am doubtful because the lines of force of two bodies of positive mass are similar to the lines of force of two positive charges. Do they repel like the charges?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're talking about Newtonian gravity and Coulombian electricity.
Actually, I would say quite the opposite: the (Newtonian) gravitational force is $\vec{F_G} =-G\frac{Mm} {r^3}\vec{r}$ while the (Coulomb) electric force is $\vec{F_E} =k\frac{Qq} {r^3}\vec{r}$. As you can see, there's a sign difference between the two, the formula itself is different, and such formulas are the ones that really tells you how to interpret the "lines of force". Since we don't know about any negative mass (one of the interpretations of the cosmological constant $\Lambda$ is that of negative energy density, but it's still speculative) then the force is always attractive.

A more complex (and complete) explanation for this lies in QFT, where the "force" is just the interaction with a "force carrier particle": the photon for electromagnetism and the graviton for gravity. Again, the difference in the behavior of those forces is to be sought in the difference between the force carriers: the photon is what you call a vector boson, while the graviton is a tensor one, and this difference yields again a sign that accounts for the different behavior.

Comment: I get it. So accordingly, we have newer and better approaches to interpret gravity than lines of force?

Comment: @Metaxylene we totally have! Our best theory of gravity is currently General Relativity. To emphasize how much this theory differs from Newtonian gravity, consider that in GR, gravity isn't even a force! It's the deformation of spacetime itself.

Comment: What I mentioned in the answer, though, is something even newer than GR. Gravitons are a (speculative) part of QFT.

Comment: Oh that's great, thanks. This means that I don't have to worry about the lines of force being a bit counter intuitive as being attractive, if there are more modern explanations.

Answer (score -2):

They do not repel as gravity in itself is not the lines, but it's field of impact is repersented by the lines. In addition, positive charges do not necessarily explain gravatational pull as mass in itself has no charge.

(DISCLAIMER: I might be very wrong as I'm only starting to study physics in secondary school)

Comment: Thanks.
Yes, gravity is not in the lines, but they were the best explanation we were able  to give before of how gravity and electrostatics work
As I'm am in high school and still learning too, I believe there may be a space time approach to it as well, but I've not learned anything about that yet